# Result of eval( arguments.callee );

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, eval

I just ran the below function in Chrome Developer Tool, but nothing happened. So what is happening - is this going to be an infinite loop?

```
function foo() {
    eval( arguments.callee );
}

foo(  );
```

If I modify the function to below:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('Called');
    eval( arguments.callee.toString() );
}

foo();
```

Output:

```
Called
```

Output is only printed one time, so whats happening?

Comment: The `eval()` will instantiate a function that looks exactly like `foo()`, but it doesn't *call* the function.

Comment: Indeed, thanks, I missed this important fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval(arguments.callee)` converts `arguments.callee` to string, which will look very much like your function declaration, and then evaluates that string — which does **not** run it, it just evaluates the function declaration, creating a function.

Your `toString` version just does the first part explicitly.

If you did `eval(arguments.callee)()` (note the `()` at the end), **that** would call it (*sort of* recursively, technically different functions are created, but...) and eventually lead to a stack overflow error.

---

Note that `arguments.callee` is disallowed in strict mode. If you need to refer to the function being called, give it a name and use the name.

Comment: Wow that was indeed quick, thanks, I missed the part that 'eval  just evaluates the function declaration, creating a function', I will accept you answer.